# mapping with multiple substitutes inserts just a newline with 'R'

Tags: key-bindings, substitute

I have this mapping in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F3> :%s/ä/\\"{a}/g<CR> :%s/ö/\\"{o}/g<CR> :%s/ü/\\"{u}/g<CR>  :%s/ß/\ss{}/g<CR>
```

after executing it, an 'R' is inserted above the current line, which of course doesn't make sense at all.

the same applies to

```
nnoremap <F3> :%s/ä/\\"{a}/g<CR>
```

How can I debug this? Is this mapping even possible?

**EDIT** [my vim config](https://github.com/toogley/dotfiles/blob/c8aad072a4335624884ac9ca1ed60ad231ec5193/vim/vimrc#L301)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you try with `vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: @muru it works when i start `vim -Nu NONE` and manually define the mapping.

Comment: Try disabling your plugins, etc.

Comment: You can try [following the steps outline here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) to isolate the problem ;-)

Comment: check your encoding option.